# using Python to modify in PDF files

Tags: python, pdf, replace

I'm using this code to convert hex to chr but how could I use it in replacing every hex found in pdf files

```
re.sub("#(..)", lambda match: chr(int(match.group(1), 16)), s)
```

I tried this but when I tried print nothing appeared

```
import re
fh = open("C:\\Users\\Suleiman JK\\Desktop\\test\\Hello.pdf","r+")
stuff = fh.read()
re.sub("#(..)", lambda match: chr(int(match.group(1), 16)), stuff)
fh.close()
fh = open("C:\\Users\\Suleiman JK\\Desktop\\test\\Hello.pdf")
print fh.read()
```

could anyone help me whith it ?

Comment: I can see where you are going -- "decrypting" object names that are "encrypted" by translating characters into # notation. But parts of PDF internals are *binary*, so willy-nilly changing anything resembling this notation will probably mess up the object offset table and any contents inside binary objects. Least you could do is test for `#` followed by two hex characters.

Comment: exactly thats what I'm going to do, but I want to search for javascript for instance and it could be represented by hex or part of its letters so I want to convert the hex to its char and search for the word hex .... could I take the pdf structure to text file and search within it ???

Comment: Yes, you can use [`qpdf`](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net), for example. `qpdf` converts a *binary* PDF into a text representation, "for people who just want to look at the innards of a PDF file to learn more about how they work". You need a pretty robust editor though; binary parts are still in binary.

Comment: please do you know any examples or references talking about how to convert from binary to text because I don't find

Comment: The first mention of `qpdf` in my comment is a hyperlink to its main page. The main page contains, amongst others, a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write nothing back to the file.

```
import re
with open("C:\\Users\\Suleiman JK\\Desktop\\test\\Hello.pdf","rb") as fh:
    stuff = fh.read()
stuff = re.sub("#(..)", lambda match: chr(int(match.group(1), 16)), stuff)
with open("C:\\Users\\Suleiman JK\\Desktop\\test\\Hello.pdf","wb") as fh:
    fh.write(stuff)
```

Comment: what should I do to browse the new pdf because I tried it and nothing appeared, could you tell me what to do please ?

Comment: then the expression #.. is not in the file. perhaps it is in the compressed parts of the file

Comment: why when I use : 
fh.open() ... print fh.read() it gives me an error ..... so what should I use to print the new modified file

Comment: *fh* has no method called *open*. Which error? reading a file is done in the lines 2 and 3 of my example.

Comment: I'm really sorry for bothering you, If I don't want to work on the original file instead I want to work on a copy of the file what should I do ??

Comment: give the outputfile another name

Comment: hello Sir sorry again, I want your help if you please. I tried the above code on two pdf files but the program gave me an error, I don't know why ......... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdf.py", line 99, in <module>
    main()
  File "pdf.py", line 35, in main
    stuff = re.sub("#([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})",lambda m:unichr(int(m.groups()[0],16)),st
uff)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: ordinal
 not in range(128)